# Text classification output save output from numpy array in CSV file

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification

I'm working on text classification problem with real data in two separate CSV files.

How you can see below I create two Numpy arrays and process classification in my Pipeline. My desire output is CSV file with X_test and Y_test. Where Y_test will contain values predicted by the classifier.

```
# coding: utf-8
# In[24]:
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('test_data4.csv',encoding='latin1', dtype={'SourcePath': str}, )
# In[25]:
import numpy as np
numpy_array = data.as_matrix()
X_train = numpy_array[:, 0]
Y_train = numpy_array[:, 1]
# In[26]:
data.head()
# In[27]:
data_test = pd.read_csv('data_go.csv',encoding='latin1', dtype={'SourcePath': str}, )
# In[28]:
data_test.head()
# In[29]:
numpy_array = data_test.as_matrix()
X_test = numpy_array[:, 0]
# In[30]:
print(X_test)
# In[31]:
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

text_clf = text_clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predicted = text_clf.predict(X_test)
np.mean(predicted == Y_test)

# In[43]:
print(pd.DataFrame(X_test, Y_test).T.to_csv(index=False, header=None))
```

Comment: If `pd.DataFrame(X_test, Y_test).T` is the dataframe you want to save, try just `pd.DataFrame(X_test, Y_test).T.to_csv(index=False, header=None)` without the `print()`

Comment: why not `df_out = pd.concat([pd.Series(X_test),pd.Series(Y_test)],axis=1)` and then `df.to_csv(path)`?

Comment: you need to modify your solution to  `pd.DataFrame([X_test,Y_test]).T.to_csv(...)`

Comment: Yes print was by mistake and `df_out = pd.concat([pd.Series(X_test),pd.Series(Y_test)],axis=1)` and `df_out.to_csv('outpoot.csv')` solve my problem. Thanks !